# How to resolve javascript objects pushed in to individual arrays instead of all of them being pushed into a single array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a javascript code as below:

```
function ready() {

    var items = document.querySelectorAll('.item')

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var current = items[i];

        var name = current.getElementsByClassName('item-title')[0].innerText;
        var price = parseInt(current.getElementsByClassName('item-price')[0].innerText);

        var data = [];

        var products = {};
        products.title = name;
        products.cost = price;
        data.push(products);

        //console.log(products)

        console.log(data)

    }
    
}
```

On running the code, I get the result as:

```
[{title: "Jack Daniels 1L", cost: 60}]
[{title: "Southern Comfort 2L", cost: 130}] 
[{title: "Golden Label 1L", cost: 120}]
[{title: "Grey Goose 1L", cost: 31}]
[{title: "Remy Martins 750ml", cost: 45}]
[{title: "Hennessy 1L", cost: 68}]
[{title: "Johnnie Walker 1L", cost: 50] 
[{title: "Double Black 750ml", cost: 55}]
```

Yet I'm looking for a result that looks like this:

```
[ {title: "Jack Daniels 1L", cost: 60}, 
   {title: "Southern Comfort 2L", cost: 130}, 
   {title: "Golden Label 1L", cost: 120}, 
   {title: "Grey Goose 1L", cost: 31}, 
   {title: "Remy Martins 750ml", cost: 45}, 
   {title: "Hennessy 1L", cost: 68}, 
   {title: "Johnnie Walker 1L", cost: 50}, 
   {title: "Double Black 750ml", cost: 55} ]
```

I have looked at solutions to questions asked that are related to mine but I keep getting the same result at best. What do I need to include or remove? Or what is the best way to go about it? Thank you.

Comment: It's because you are defining a new `data` array at each iteration, move the `var data = []` out of the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is due to `data` being defined in each iteration. Move it out and it will work

```
function ready() {

    var items = document.querySelectorAll('.item')

    var data = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var current = items[i];

        var name = current.getElementsByClassName('item-title')[0].innerText;
        var price = parseInt(current.getElementsByClassName('item-price')[0].innerText);

        var products = {};
        products.title = name;
        products.cost = price;
        data.push(products);

        //console.log(products)

    }

   console.log(data)
    
}
```

Comment: Your input has seen great improvement in my result, the `Objects` are added individually with each iteration i.e my result has 7 arrays each with one more object that the previous one  as: `[{title: "Jack Daniels 1L", cost: 60}] (1)
[{title: "Jack Daniels 1L", cost: 60}, {title: "Southern Comfort 2L", cost: 130}] (2)
[Log] [{title: "Jack Daniels 1L", cost: 60}, {title: "Southern Comfort 2L", cost: 130}, {title: "Golden Label 1L", cost: 120}] (3)...` Is it possible to target the very last array which has what I need?

Comment: yes to target the last item in an array you can do

`var item = data[data.length -1]`

Please mark this as accepted if it has helped you resolve your question

Comment: It appears there's a little misunderstanding...I'm getting 8 different arrays as my result, of the 8 arrays the first has only one object, the second has two, this continues to increase by one with each succeeding array til the eighth that has all the objects. My concern is that am I getting 8 different arrays as opposed to just one that has everything I want. Out of the eight arrays, only the eighth has all the objects as I desire. How do I ensure that it is only one that is output as the result?